# calculate total based on distinct order_id, mysql

Tags: mysql

i need to calculate sum of total based on distinct order_id from my mysql table. In my table i am having order cart where order_id is repeated as each order is having multiple items, and i am also keeping the total in the same table. but here total value is repeated since order_id is also getting repeated based on different items of the cart. So i want to calculate the total sales for the day based on distinct order_id.

```
$stmt = $linkID1->prepare("select sum(total) 
         from sales_data 
         where STR_TO_DATE(order_date, '%d-%m-%Y') between STR_TO_DATE('$today', '%d-%m-%Y') 
                and STR_TO_DATE('$today', '%d-%m-%Y') and store_code='$scode'");
```

in this query, its showing sum of all the totals based on all the order_id, since order_id is repeating so its taking all the total, but i need dintinct total based on distinct order_id

Comment: That query doesn't match what you say it does.  Could you change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select sum(total) 
 from
 (
    select distinct order_id, total from sales_data 
    where STR_TO_DATE(order_date, '%d-%m-%Y') between STR_TO_DATE('$today', '%d-%m-%Y') 
       and STR_TO_DATE('$today', '%d-%m-%Y') and store_code='$scode'
 )
```

Comment: tried this query but getting the following error -- #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: fixed the issue, thnx buddy, your query helped me a lot